# Zuul Api Gateway mapped wrong service url (character set)?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, special-characters, microservices, netflix-zuul

Im trying to create microservices but zuul api gateway service maped wrong url. Seems it is related to encoding problem.

Zuul application.properties

```
spring.application.name=zuul-api-gateway
server.port=8765

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Service application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: car-service
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/car_service_db?useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: admin
  profiles:
    active: local
server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Other service application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: company-service
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/company_service_db?useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: admin
server:
  port: 8081

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka


management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Eureka logs:

```
2018-02-11 00:02:41.204  INFO 22672 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance CAR-SERVICE/localhost:car-service:8080 with status UP (replication=false)
2018-02-11 00:02:58.469  INFO 22672 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2018-02-11 00:03:06.468  INFO 22672 --- [nio-8761-exec-4] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance COMPANY-SERVICE/localhost:company-service:8081 with status UP (replication=false)
2018-02-11 00:03:26.139  INFO 22672 --- [nio-8761-exec-9] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance ZUUL-API-GATEWAY/localhost:zuul-api-gateway:8765 with status UP (replication=false)
```

And the zuul logs

```
2018-02-11 00:03:35.037  INFO [zuul-api-gateway,6944cfba5180a640,6944cfba5180a640,false] 2132 --- [nio-8765-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/car-servıce/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
2018-02-11 00:05:06.872  INFO [zuul-api-gateway,773aa5fc779af5e6,773aa5fc779af5e6,false] 2132 --- [nio-8765-exec-3] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/company-servıce/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
2018-02-11 00:05:06.873  INFO [zuul-api-gateway,773aa5fc779af5e6,773aa5fc779af5e6,false] 2132 --- [nio-8765-exec-3] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/zuul-apı-gateway/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
```

In the zuul logs, all services mapped by special letter with 'ı' which is the turkish character instead of 'i' and i can not reach my services via zuul api gateway.

I have also tried override Zuul configuration in this example : [Spring-Cloud Zuul breaks UTF-8 symbols in forwarded multipart request filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881610/spring-cloud-zuul-breaks-utf-8-symbols-in-forwarded-multipart-request-filename)

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    FormBodyWrapperFilter formBodyWrapperFilter() {
        return new FormBodyWrapperFilter(new MyFormHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    private class MyFormHttpMessageConverter extends FormHttpMessageConverter {

        private byte[] getAsciiBytes(String name) {
            try {
                // THIS IS THE ONLY MODIFICATION:
                return name.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                // Should not happen - US-ASCII is always supported.
                throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when i try call service via Zuul api gateway, it returns 404 not found.

Im using spring-boot 2.0.0.M3, spring-cloud Finchley.M2 versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by create extended EurekaDiscoveryClient just for toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) option.

```
import com.netflix.appinfo.EurekaInstanceConfig;
import com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient;
import com.netflix.discovery.shared.Application;
import com.netflix.discovery.shared.Applications;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.*;

@Component
public class CustomEurekaDiscoveryClient extends EurekaDiscoveryClient implements DiscoveryClient {


    private final EurekaInstanceConfig config;

    private final EurekaClient eurekaClient;

    public CustomEurekaDiscoveryClient(EurekaInstanceConfig config, @Qualifier("eurekaClient") EurekaClient eurekaClient) {
        super(config, eurekaClient);
        this.config = config;
        this.eurekaClient = eurekaClient;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getServices() {
        Applications applications = this.eurekaClient.getApplications();
        if (applications == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<Application> registered = applications.getRegisteredApplications();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Application app : registered) {
            if (app.getInstances().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            names.add(app.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));

        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

Upper case 'I' transform to lower case 'ı' not 'i' in Turkish OS and jvm that's why i need to override the **public List getServices()** method.

If the toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) method calls without **Locale.ROOT** java transform character to 'ı' but use the **Locale.ROOT** option, method transform to 'i' and project works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Spring boot, I will suggest you to use annotation for zuul gateway and create custom filter for zuul that will take care for each and every thing.

Please find the code below and see whether it works for you or not :

> Main Class

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = { Constants.FEIGN_BASE_PACKAGE })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { Constants.BASE_PACKAGE, Constants.LOGGING_PACKAGE })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { Constants.ENTITY_BASE_PACKAGE })
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayInitializer {

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "30");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Initializer.class, args);

    }
```

> ZUUL Filter

```
package com.sxm.aota.gateway.filters;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException;


/**
 * This CustomErrorFilter involve to handle ZuulException.
 */
public class CustomErrorFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    /** The logger. */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomErrorFilter.class);
    /** The message source. */
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    /** The properties. */
    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter#filterType()
     */
    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter#filterOrder()
     */
    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return -1; // Needs to run before SendErrorFilter which has filterOrder == 0
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.netflix.zuul.IZuulFilter#shouldFilter()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        // only forward to errorPath if it hasn't been forwarded to already
        return RequestContext.getCurrentContext().containsKey("error.status_code");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.netflix.zuul.IZuulFilter#run()
     */
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        try {
            RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
            Object e = ctx.get("error.exception");
            if (e != null && e instanceof ZuulException) {
                ZuulException zuulException = (ZuulException) e;
                logger.error("Zuul failure detected: " + zuulException.getMessage(), zuulException);
                // Remove error code to prevent further error handling in follow up filters
                ctx.remove("error.status_code");

                } else {
                    error.setMessage(messageSource.getMessage(Constants.REQUESTED_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, new Object[] { zuulException.getCause() }, properties.getCurrentLocale()));
                    ctx.setResponseBody(mapper.writeValueAsString(error));
                    ctx.getResponse().setContentType("application/json");
                    ctx.setResponseStatusCode(500); // Can set any error code as excepted
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception filtering in custom error filter", ex);
            ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add Locale.setDefault for english in main method of Zuul application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
    SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
}
```

it solves your problem too.